# function not executing for the second time after onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

An animation that is supposed to work in the 3rd slide of a JQuery slider is working fine the first time but not the second and consecutive times. The animation is tied in with the next button of the slider. Clicking the next button removes the "show" attribute from the current slide and adds the "show" attribute to the next slide. I have tried for days to debug this by researching similar scenarios and trying out different solutions but sofar it's a no go. Can anyone help?

```
function dog(){
    var dog = document.getElementById('dog_2');
    TweenMax.to(dog, 2, {left:"325px", repeat:2, yoyo:true});
}

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 300, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('#slider').on('click', 'a.control_next', function (){
    moveRight();

    if($("li").next().length > 0){
        var next = $("#slider .slideshow .show").removeClass("show").next("li");
        next.addClass("show");
    } 

    else if  {
        $("li:last").removeClass("show");
        $("li:first").addClass("show");
    }

    if ($("li").eq(2).hasClass("show")){
        dog();
    };
});
```

Comment: if possible post your code in a jsFiddle .. need to see HTML too

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaPWGg

Comment: thanks for checking it out.

Comment: did you check below answer by GAL V.. did it work,, ? $(document).on('click', '#slider a.control_next', function (){ }); should do the trick

Comment: posted working solution.. refer my answer for problem description . http://jsfiddle.net/bbe0Lstu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, each time you click on next or previous button a call to dog() function creates a new tweenmax animation instance on destination div. Multiple animation instances make it hang.

Approach 1: [First jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/bbe0Lstu/4/), Maintain one tweenmax animation object. Just restart it on certain condition by calling dog(); function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var animate;
  var doggy = document.getElementById('dog_2');  
  animate = TweenMax.to(doggy, 2, {left:"325px", repeat:true, yoyo:true}); 

   function dog(){ 
     animate.restart();    
   } 
  ...........
  .............
  });
```

Approach 2: [Second jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbe0Lstu/2/). Create destination DIV by injecting HTML using jQuery. suitable for dynamic scenarios.

```
function dog(){
  var dog = document.getElementById('dog_2');  
  dog.remove();  
  $("li.dog").html("<div id=\"dog_2\"><img src=\"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif\" style=\"height:50px;width:50px\"/></div>");
  var dog = $('#dog_2');
  //TweenMax.killTweensOf(dog);     
  animate =TweenMax.to(dog, 2, {left:"325px", repeat:true, yoyo:true});  
  animate.play();    
}  


$('#slider').on('click', 'a.control_next,a.control_prev', function (){
    if($(this).hasClass('control_next'))
    {moveRight();}
    else{ moveLeft();}
    var prev = $("#slider .slideshow .show").removeClass("show").next("li");
    prev.addClass("show");
    if ($("li").eq(2).hasClass("show")){
      // call dog(); on some condition if required.
    }; 
    dog();
});
```

Comment: Wow, very impressive. Would you recommend the one approach above the other?

Comment: if i were you, i would have opted for approach 1 because of its simplicity and easier to manage for slider, and also it doesn't loads the code again, it will just restart animation.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to put this together!

Answer (score 1):

So there are several things wrong with this snippet of code.

1. `else if  {` must have a `(condition)`, otherwise just use `else {`.
2. You are switching the order of the slides in your 300-millisecond long animation, making the reliability of `eq(2)` very poor. Everytime you click *Next*, `eq(2)` will be different. In fact, the only way to hit it is if you repeatedly click the *Next* link three times within these 300-milliseconds. I propose using a `class` or a `data-attribute` instead; something that won't change regardless of the state of the slideshow.
3. Last, but not least, to answer your question... it *supposed* to only work once. In order to make the animation work multiple times, you will need to "rewind" [`reverse()`](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/reverse/) it before you can play it again.

Check out my what I did below. Hope it helps!

```js
var animation = null;

function dog(){
    if (animation !== null) {
        animation.reverse(-2);
    }
    
    var dog = document.getElementById('dog_2');
    animation = TweenMax.to(dog, 2, {left:"325px", repeat:2, yoyo:true});
}

function moveRight() {
    var slideWidth = 325;
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 300, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('#slider').on('click', 'a.control_next', function (){
    moveRight();

    if($("li").next().length > 0){
        var next = $("#slider .slideshow .show").removeClass("show").next("li");
        next.addClass("show");
    } 

    else {
        $("li:last").removeClass("show");
        $("li:first").addClass("show");
    }

    if ($("li").attr("data-dog") === "true"){
        dog();
    }
});
```

```css
#dog_2 {
    position: absolute;
}

.control_next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
}

li {
    display: none;
    width: 325px;
    height: 325px;
    background: lightblue;
}

li.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dog_2">dog</div>
<div id="slider">
    <ul class="slideshow">
        <li class="show">a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li data-dog="true">c - dog</li>
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="control_next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion re the data-attribute. I already noticed the animation changing and was wondering what that was caused by. I implemented the changes but did not get it to work which may be due to the fact that you only had a snippet of code. Thanks for the help.